# Date data type coming up as 12:00 am

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, types, sqldatatypes

Ok.  In visual studio I have a table to display a summery of data.  All of my data with the "date" datatype comes up with the with the date that we entered.  However they all show 12:00 AM after the date.  The following is some sample output when I tie this table to a webform.

Edit Delete Details  6/20/2012 12:00:00 AM  28
Edit Delete Details  6/21/2012 12:00:00 AM  11
Edit Delete Details  6/25/2012 12:00:00 AM  34
Edit Delete Details  6/26/2012 12:00:00 AM  14
Edit Delete Details  6/27/2012 12:00:00 AM  45
Edit Delete Details  6/29/2012 12:00:00 AM

Can I fix the 12:00AM to time entered or the current time?

I do not want to use varchar or int or any other data type becasue when our employees look at our data summary it sorts it by the primary key.  With the other data types it sorts it wrong.

Thanks again.

I am working with Visual studio 2010 its a C# web app and SLQ Server 2012 Enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

In your data control, where you bind your data to the visual elements, you'll have to add a StringFormat of dd/MM/yyyy

For Example, if you are binding to an asp.net GridView, you have to set up your field bound to the DateTime type field somewhat like this:

`<asp:BoundField DataField="MyDateField" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" 
                    HeaderText="MyDateFieldHeader" SortExpression="MyDateField" />`

Comment: "Date" is the name of My data field but it says it cant find it.  I take it this goes into the default.aspx or where ever the table comes up.

Comment: It would really be much better if you could just paste some code where you are binding the data. Also, edit your question to specify which technology you are using. ASP.Net? ASP.Net MVC? Silverlight? or anything else?

Comment: I am not going to copy and past code here.  I am telling you 12:00 AM is a default vaule or property of time somewhere in some option that visual studio has.  The above code you did just got rid of the time.  And if it comes to that I will use your code if I cannot edit the time on the listing.  I cannot find this on any site anywhere I try to google.  I looked up the DataFormatString on MSDN and no matter what I do it still comes up 12:00AM.

Answer (score 0):

In the .aspx file where you want to remove the time, Just format the data out with date only as shown in the code below

Comment: <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" SortExpression  ="Date"  />